# How to find this Zendesk widget code in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: Zendesk chat widget, need to find a code from this]

I tried to search everywhere but still found nothing. I can't remember where i put it

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities on where the code could be located in the Magento 1.9 Admin.

My guess would you will find it in:
System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts